# API Wildberries помогите правильно составить POST запрос

Tags: api, post, запрос, wildberries

Пробую работать с API (post) от Wildberries в power querry: [https://openapi.wb.ru/promotion/api/ru/#tag/Statistika/paths/~1adv~1v2~1fullstats/post](https://openapi.wb.ru/promotion/api/ru/#tag/Statistika/paths/%7E1adv%7E1v2%7E1fullstats/post)

```
let
// Задаем URL
url = "https://advert-api.wb.ru/adv/v2/fullstats",

// Задаем параметры запроса в формате JSON
requestBody = "{""id"":idcompany, ""dates"":[""2024-01-01 & 2024-02-01""]}",

// Отправляем POST запрос с использованием API ключа в заголовке запроса
response = Web.Contents(
url,
[
Headers = [
#"Content-Type"="application/json",
#"Authorization"="API KEY"
],
Content = Text.ToBinary(requestBody)
]
),

// Преобразуем ответ в формат JSON
jsonResponse = Json.Document(response)
in
jsonResponse
```

Подскажите что я делаю не так... Выводит ошибку 400 и 405 (авторизацию не проходит) Ключи и создавали новые и idcompany меняли